# Apache Camel : How to setHeader value as null

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-camel

How do we set header value as null in apache camel exchange message from a processor. I am delivering message to a RabbitMQ exchange and it expects one of the header value to be set as null.

I have tried below approaches from my processor just before delivering the message

```
exchange.getOut().setHeader("headername","");
```

But this sets up an empty string to the header.

I also tried

```
exchange.getOut().setHeader("headername",null);
```

But in this case the header itself is not visible.

Please let me know if any more information is needed.

Comment: Whats the use-case for having a null header, eg is it some special header or what is it.

Comment: @ClausIbsen `and it expects one of the header value to be set as null.`. I assume he just wants to remove / null one of the header values not the entire header.

Comment: The service which reads this message expects the header to be present, but it should have a null value. Exactly as explained by @BjoernRennhak. If I set it to null type, the entire header disappears.

Comment: Maybe `exchange.getOut().setHeader("headername", constant("") );` will achieve what you want?

Answer (score 1):

The camel-rabbitmq component does not support headers with `null` values. They are filtered out in the source code.

https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/fab7a58e56e128286f327aba16c09553b26cb846/components/camel-rabbitmq/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/rabbitmq/RabbitMQMessageConverter.java#L171

Its a odd requirement/use-case to have to send a null value. And hence why I ask you to explain this more. There must be very good reason to consider changing Camel.

Comment: I investigated further and found that the java client for RabbitMQ allows the header to be null. However, the apache-camel converter for RabbitMQ performs this null check and filters out the header if it has null value. From the technical perspective, it could be an odd requirement, but it is a specification that I need to adhere to. The RabbitMQ exchange and the other services integrating with it expect headers to be set as null (to route messages to other integrations)

Comment: Okay then log a JIRA ticket in Apache Camel, and point to this SO and it would be good with a link to that java client where you can see it allows null values

Comment: Would it be possible for you to share link to JIRA for apache camel. I will log a new ticket. I also have some available time this summer, so may be I can help with some contributions.

Comment: There is a link to issue tracker (Jira) on this page: http://camel.apache.org/support.html

Answer (score 0):

Camel has implemented a fix for this which is backported to the 2.22.1 and 2.21.3 versions and will be available there onwards. For those who are interested to know how this can be achieved, please have a look at [Camel-12654](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-12654) Jira issue.

[camel-rabbitmq](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-rabbitmq/src/main/docs/rabbitmq-component.adoc) component and endpoint now support a URI option `allowNullHeaders` which is false by default. If you want to send custom headers with value as null, set its value to true. For example

`from("rabbitmq://hostname:port/exchangeName?allowNullHeaders=true").....`

This will configure camel-rabbitmq converter to set headers with null values. Now from your processor, you can do something like this

`exchange.getOut().setHeader("headername",null);`

This will instruct camel-rabbitmq producer, not to skip and headers which have null values.